# PostgreSQL 11: How to restrict privileges to stored functions?

Tags: postgresql

How can I restrict the privileges of a PostgreSQL role to access only functions
already present in a schema, so no individual `SELECT` or `INSERT` queries are allowed?

I've created a new user:

```
$ createuser --no-superuser --createdb --no-createrole --pwprompt myuser
$ createdb --encoding UTF8 --owner myuser mydatabase
```

Then, I added my schema with all tables and functions for table access:

```
$ psql -h localhost -U myuser -d mydatabase -a -f myschema.sql
```

Is it sufficient do drop all privileges for role `myuser` and them just:

```
myuser=> GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA myschema TO myuser;
```

Or should I create a distinct role? Can this role access a schema whom it is not the owner of?

Comment: You seem to be going at it from a bizarre direction. If `myuser` is meant to be restricted, why do you make it the owner of the database and schema objects in the first place? You should probably use a separate administrative role to create objects, _then_ only grant specific privileges to `myuser`.

Comment: I wondering what privileges have to be set specifically, as I get `permission denied for schema myschema` for a distinct role, despite `USAGE` rights have been granted.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a function to give a user access to otherwise inaccessible data, you need to define it as `SECURITY DEFINER` and make the owner a user with the required privileges on the data.

Don't forget to

- ```
  REVOKE EXECUTE ON FUNCTION myfunc FROM PUBLIC;
  ```

  because by default, everybody can execute a function
- ```
  ALTER FUNCTION myfunc SET search_path = ..., pg_temp;
  ```

  so that the function is safe from privilege escalation attacks.